# How to retrieve an image from an OData Service?

Tags: c#, odata

I have an OData service (its System Center Orchestrator's web service if you must know ) that returns a BMP image if I query

**http://localhost.com/Orchestrator2012/Orchestrator.svc/RunbookDiagrams(guid'882f767d-63bd-437c-b0c7-4051aac56176')/$value**

So its basically saying, give me the RunbookDiagram with the Id 882f767d-63bd-437c-b0c7-4051aac56176

It renders it correctly in IE. But when I query it fom C# I'm not able to get the image data, but I do get all other data fields.

Now the documentation of the webservice says I need to use $value to return the query. But how do I use $value in the following OData query from C#

```
RunbookDiagram rbkdiag=orch.RunbookDiagrams.Where(
                                                  m => m.RunbookId ==runbookId
                                                 ).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the service is returning the images as media link entries?
You can check for this by viewing the xml returned from the server and look for m:HasStream="true"

If this is the case use [GetReadStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.getreadstream) on the context.

Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/09/08/data-services-streaming-provider-series-part-2-accessing-a-media-resource-stream-from-the-client.aspx) astoriateam blog post for details.